# What is the difference between `::` and `.` in pig?

Tags: apache-pig

What is the difference between `::` and `.` in `pig`?

When do I use one vs the other?

E.g., I know that `::` is need in `join` when a field exists in both aliases:

```
A = foreach (join B by (x), C by (y)) generate B::y as b_y, C::y as c_y;
```

and I need `.` when accessing `group` fields:

```
A = foreach (group B by (x,y)) generate group.x as x, group.y as y, SUM(B?z) as z;
```

However, do I pass `B::z` or `B.z` to `SUM` above instead of `B?z`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIRC you get `::` as a side effect after some statements. You cannot bother about it, unless (as you mentioned) a name exists inside two different prefixes.

The `.` is different in that you are going inside the structure.
`group.x as x, group.y as y` is equivalent to `FLATTEN(group)`

`SUM(B?z)` - here you should do `SUM(B.z)`, to specify that you need a particular field to `SUM`.

Comment: `FLATTEN(group)` creates fields `group::x` and `group::y`, not `x` and `y`.

Comment: I suppose you can still reference them by 'x' or 'y' unless there are other 'x' and/or 'y'. Let me know if that is not true.

Comment: the problem is that after feeding aliases through several `group` and `join` operations, I get errors if I use `FLATTEN` instead of explicit `group.x as x`, e.g., `there is no field A::x, only A::B::x`.

Comment: I am not aware unless i see the full picture:) Anyways it seems that WinnieNicklaus put a very good answer.

Comment: @sds You are correct, if you use multiple commands which do this disambiguation, you cannot skip intermediate names -- if you have `A::B::x`, you can refer to it as `x` or `A::B::x`, but not `A::x`.

Answer (score 5):

In Pig, `::` is used as a disambiguation tool after operations which could possibly create naming collisions.  Notably, this happens with `JOIN`, `CROSS`, and `FLATTEN`. Consider two relations, `A:{(id:int, name:chararray)}` and `B:{(id:int, location:chararray)}`.  If you want to associate names with locations, naturally you would do:

```
C = JOIN A BY id, B BY id;
```

Without the disambiguation operator, your schema would be

```
C:{(id:int, name:chararray, id:int, location:chararray)}
```

Now you can't tell which field `id` refers to.  To avoid this, Pig will instead do

```
C:{(A::id:int, A::name:chararray, B::id:int, B::location:chararray)}
```

Likewise, you could `FLATTEN` two bags whose tuples have fields with the same name, and they would also collide.  So the same operator is used in this case as well.  When there is no such conflict, you do not need to use the full name: `name` is unambiguous here. To simplify `C`, then, you can do this:

```
D = FOREACH C GENERATE A::id, name, location;
```

---

The `.` operator, by contrast, projects fields from bags and tuples.  If you have a bag `b` with schema `{(x:int, y:int, z:int)}`, the projection `b.y` yields a bag with just the specified field: `{(y:int)}`.  You can project multiple fields at once with parentheses: `b.(y,z)` yields `{(y:int, z:int)}`.

When used with tuples, the result is a tuple with just the specified fields.  If the tuple `t` has schema `(x:int, y:int, z:int)`, then `t.x` is the tuple `(x:int)` and `t.(y,z)` is the tuple `(y:int, z:int)`.

---

To your specific question about `SUM`, note that `SUM` along with the other summary statistic UDFs, takes a bag as its argument.  Therefore, you need to create a bag with just the one field per tuple that you want to sum.  Using the projection operator, `.`: `B.z`.